# Setting Multiple Variables to the Same Value in One Line

Tags: applescript

Hey I am wondering if there is a way to collapse this bit of code, so its not 12 lines of setting variables.

Current Code:

```
set isVideo to false
set isTV to false
set isMovie to false
set isRawVideo to false
set isDocumentary to false
set isAudio to false
set isSports to false
set isUnknown to false
set toPrompt to false
set BTNChoice to ""
set keyword to ""
set keywordHit to ""
```

What I'm hoping for:

```
set (isVideo, isTV, isMovie, isRawVideo, isDocumentary, isAudio, isSports, isUnknown, toPrompt) to false
set (BTNChoice, keyword, keywordHit) to ""
```

Or:

```
isVideo = isTV = isMovie = isRawVideo = isDocumentary = isAudio = isSports = isUnknown = toPrompt = false
BTNChoice = keyword = keywordHit = ""
```

Let me know if theres a way to reduce this or if I'm stuck with one variable per line.

Ryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only one-liner way is

```
set {isVideo, isTV, isMovie, isRawVideo, isDocumentary, isAudio, isSports, isUnknown, toPrompt} to {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false}
set {BTNChoice, keyword, keywordHit} to {"", "", ""}
```

Or even a *real* one-liner

```
set {isVideo, isTV, isMovie, isRawVideo, isDocumentary, isAudio, isSports, isUnknown, toPrompt, BTNChoice, keyword, keywordHit} to {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, "", "", ""}
```

The number of items on the right side must not be less than the number of items on the left side.